# Sending email based on a vlookup cell generated by a form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I'm looking for a script that would send an automatic email to a seller (column J) when a change is made to one of his customers. The change is made through a google form. So the form is linked to a spreadsheet and I added a tab where I did a vlookup in column J of the customer number. It works when I manually typed the email adress but it doesn't when it's the vlookup formula... here's the code I have for now.

Thanks in advance.

```
function twchange3(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (e.range.getColumn()== 10) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var value = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).getValues();
    var email = value[0][9];
    var router = value[0][1];
    var noclient = value[0][3];
    var nomclient = value[0][4];
    var twactuel = value[0][5];
    var twdemande = value[0][6];
    var raison = value[0][7];
    MailApp.sendEmail(value[0][9], "Demande de changement de Time-Window", 
                      "Bonjour voici une demande de changement de Time-Window pour votre client " + nomclient + "\n\n" + 
                      "Numéro de client: " + noclient + "\n\n" + 
                      "Time-Window Actuel: " + twactuel + "\n\n" + 
                      "Time-Window demandé: " + twdemande + "\n\n" + 
                      "Raison: " + raison + "\n\n" +
                      "Auteur de la demande: " + router + "\n\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your saying but I'm guessing that you made a change on a sheet manually which triggered an onEdit() trigger which then sent the email.  But when the change does not involve a user edit then the email is not.  **And that is normal behavior because onEdit events are only created by user actions.**  But you might be able to send the email by using an onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What's the purpose of the VLOOKUP? A sanitized copy of the spreadsheet could be useful to understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks Cooper but because the recipient of the email is in another tab is there something i need to change in the code itself or do I need to simply change the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase what you've said.

- A client submits a Google Form, which sends a **result** to *Tab A* of a Google Sheet.
- Then there is *Tab B* that is using a VLOOKUP function to check the latest **result** in the Google Sheet.
- When you change a cell with the email manually in *Tab A*, the script works.
- When you use the Google Form to submit a response, the script does not run.

There are a few problems here.

When you manually change the Sheet, you activate the onEdit trigger.
When you update the Sheet via the Google Form, it is unlikely that onEdit gets triggered because onEdit is normally a user domain. It is likely that onChange is supposed to be triggered instead, and you might not even have it set up.
Then, even if you set up onChange and it fires, I'd say it is unlikely that the change will be occurring in the VLOOKUP cell of *Tab B* because the latter is just a filter, and the actual change is likely to be happening in *Tab A*. I am saying *likely* because I decided not to test it since your description of the issue was not very clear.

So you do not actually need VLOOKUP here, just read the changing cell directly with the script.

Even a better solution might be reading the response directly from the Google Form with its own script and triggers.

Comment: I'll try to make it more clear. We want to use a google form to automatically advise a sales rep that we are making some changes on one of his customer. Basically the form asks for a customer number and the description of the changes. The form is linked to a google sheet tab, then in another tab i'm using the index formula to copy what's in the linked tab and on the column after im using a vlookup of the customer number to get the email adress of the sales rep but because it's a formula i think google sheet doesn't detect that i'm making an edit or a change (i tried both trigger)